# Can a well-formed HTTP Request contain "NULL"?

Tags: http

My OCSP client is sending me the following HTTP request:

```
POST <NULL> HTTP/1.0
  Content-Type: application/ocsp-request
  Content-Length: 120
```

The NULL is not mentioned in the [RFC for HTTP 1.0](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1945.html). Does that make this a malformed request?

Comment: For clarification, are they sending you *nothing*, ie. `POST  HTTP/1.0`, or the literal string `<NULL>`?

Comment: @tloflin: the literal string <NULL>, at least that's what Wireshark captures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 5.1.2 of your RFC says:

1. The Request-URI is a Uniform Resource Identifier (Section 3.2)
2. Note that the absolute path cannot be empty

So according to it, `<NULL>` is not a valid Request URI.